# Restrict b2MouseJoint movement to x axis without effecting gravity

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have set up an object that falls from the top of the screen using box2d gravity. I am now implementing the ability to move the object using a b2MouseJoint as set out in the following [article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/28604/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial-part-1).

My question is how can i just effect the x axis movement with the mousejoint and leave gravity to take care of the y axis.

I have tried using the code in the article to limit the movement but that just stops the object from falling at all.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a b2LineJoint instead? That allows you to constrain a body along a single axis (in your case, you'd want it to be constrained along a vertical line).